# Linq and DataSetExtensions warnings using .NET Framework 2.0 and C# 3

Tags: c#, .net

I am receiving the following warnings:

> Warning   1   Could not resolve assembly
>   System.Xml.Linq. The target framework
>   required by this assembly (3.5) is
>   higher than the project target
>   framework. If this reference is
>   required by your code, you may get
>   compilation
>   errors.   ConsoleApplication1
>
> Warning   2   Could not resolve assembly
>   System.Data.DataSetExtensions. The
>   target framework required by this
>   assembly (3.5) is higher than the
>   project target framework. If this
>   reference is required by your code,
>   you may get compilation
>   errors.   ConsoleApplication1
>
> Warning   3   The referenced component
>   'System.Xml.Linq' could not be found.
>
> Warning   4   The referenced component
>   'System.Data.DataSetExtensions' could
>   not be found.

Do you know how to fix them? My project needs to target .NET2.0, but I am allowed to use C# 3 features if they are supported.

Comment: By "remove", you mean "fix" and not "ignore", right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` is part of .NET 3.5; it *might* work simply by bundling the dll, but that isn't the supported route. The "fix" here is to either target .NET 3.5 and have .NET 3.5 as a pre-requisite; or don't use DataSetExtensions (use regular access instead; perhpas with some LINQBridge and just write the missing extension methods you want yourself).

If you *aren't* using DataSetExtensions in your code, then just remove the unnecessary references to System.Data.DataSetExtensions and System.Xml.Linq (in solution explorer).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio 2008, target the project to use .NET 3.5.  If you are using Visual Studio 2005, you'll need to upgrade to 2008 to use LINQ.

Comment: The project needs to be .NET2 compatible